# How can i reshape TFRecord dataset to train RNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to feed an RNN model with `.tfrecords` datasets (train,test) in order to train it. But i am getting an error about the size of input0. 
I think `train_data` wants to reshape to 4 dims but i am not sure.

---

The bellow function returning the datasets from `.tfrecords` with features and one hot encoded label.

```
def get_dataset(directory, num_classes=60, batch_size=32, drop_remainder=False,
                shuffle=False, shuffle_size=1000):
    # dictionary describing the features.
    feature_description = {
        'features': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }

    # parse each proto and, the features within
    def _parse_feature_function(example_proto):
        features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
        data = tf.io.parse_tensor(features['features'], tf.float32)
        label = tf.one_hot(features['label'], num_classes)
        data = tf.reshape(data, (3, 300, 25, 2))
        return data, label

    records = [os.path.join(directory, file) for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.endswith("tfrecord")]
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(records, num_parallel_reads=len(records))
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_feature_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=drop_remainder)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_size)
    return dataset

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_data = get_dataset('/TfRecords/xsub/')
    test_data = get_dataset('/TfRecords/xview/')
    print(train_data)

   # create LSTM
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 100, 32
    n_features=60
    n_length = 32
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, n_length, n_features)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
                        validation_data=test_data)
```

The displayed error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 3, 300, 25, 2]

Comment: Can you please provide the test and train data shapes?

Comment: Tensorflow Timedistruted_Conv1D layer expects input of shape 4D. Change the input shape accordingly. Or use `TimeDistributed_Conv2D` layer. `TimeDistributed(Conv1D)` layer expects input of shape 5D. For more information read this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed). Thanks!